# Library for generating natural language (verbs) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a good js library or function for creating natural phrases/sentences?
specifically, I have random things like "bird", "pencil" "football player" etc
and I want to be able to construct a sentence that would fit with the noun ... "johnny has 7 pencils"
"johnny has seen 3 birds"
"suzy knows 10 more football players"

the goal is to randomly generate sentences that can be modeled with algebraic expressions. It's easy enough except for generating a natural verb and getting the correct tense.

I looked briefly into natural language processing, but (at least on the surface) it mostly it looks like it goes the other way.

can you suggest a library, or if not, perhaps suggest an outline for an algorithm I could create?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very complicated, some even say impossible and I think that is the reason your question got down-voted. But your specific problem has-to some extend-a solution if you are OK with the restriction to not-overly-complicated sentences.

The basic English grammar is quite simple: subject, predicate, and object. So with a list of nouns and verbs you are already able to build grammatically correct sentences. The most difficult thing is to get the lists or build them yourself (e.g.: from some dictionary like the public domain 1913 version of Webster's) but the Internet offers several such lists.

If you have more lists (adjectives, adverbs, etc.) you can build more complex sentences. There are also lists with irregular verbs, uncommon plurals or nouns etc.

To makes things simpler I would not look for arbitrary sentences but build a bunch of them myself and allow some random generator to fill in the words from the correct list. With the simplest form SPO:

`simpelSentence = randNoun() + randVerb() + randObject();`

To some more complex form:

`notSoSimpleSentence = randNoun() + randVerb() + randAdjective() + randObject();`

Build more templates that way and if you have enough: start filling them, check the output and be disappointed. It does not work very good, you need to implement more rules like e.g.: `he has` but `they have` etc. and rest assured it needs many such rules even for the simplest sentences.

There are several scripts out there that can "write" scientific papers for you. The first hit from a Google search is [SCIgen](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/scigen) although it is [written in Perl](https://github.com/strib/scigen). These programs are known as "paper generators" and Lo! and Behold-they have a [wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_generator). If you follow that page one step higher you'll find the Category [Natural Language Generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Natural_language_generation) with some more information. This paragraph has some sentences…my…really hard to construct!

If you still want to do it: make lists with n-grams. Or use [Google's n-gram lists](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html) (huge page with a lot of links to n-gram lists auto-generated by Google although of high quality) but be careful, these lists are *huge*. No, really, they are **huge**! Which means that you cannot just wrap them in an `Array` and use them directly. A megabyte or two are probably acceptable today (text-files compress well) but more than 100 gigabytes? So you have to dust off your word-washing pan and get the needed nuggets.

And after all of that hassle: how to you teach these sentences to make sense? How to avoid to put the bald man's nicely combed maroon hair up in rollers?

Nope, this problem had an overdose of a phosphodiesterase type 5 inhibitor (a non-psychoactive piperazine), sorry. An injection of methylene blue directly into the problem had been considered but assumed to only leave a monochromatic mess.

But serious: anything above some very simple sentences filled from some short lists with a handful of rules is out of reach for a little ECMA-script script written over a weekend or two.